# Add a custom header in http get request angularjs.

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-resource, angularjs-http

This is my angularjs request.

```
var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/test',
                headers: {
                    "x-auth-token" : user.token
                }
            }

            $http(req).success(function(){
                console.log("yes you have done it");
            }).error(function(){
                console.log("oopsss");
            });
```

I got this exception when I call this request.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/test. Invalid HTTP
>   status code 403

However in postman test of google chrome it works well and return me the response as I expect. I get this as.

The request header in postman test

```
GET /appraisal HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
x-auth-token: 123456
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

And in the response header.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 27 Mar 2015 16:13:46 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

But when I call my get request the brower shows http request header like this.

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, x-auth-token
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:52.11.111.128:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/james/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
```

And http response header is

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-auth-token
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 27 Mar 2015 17:03:16 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

I have enable cross request origin policy in my server.

How to request the header correctly ?

how to resolve this issue in my controller.

Please guide me towards this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We use a service for that which set the header for all requests against the REST-API. The service set the authorization header and looks like this:

```
app.factory('api', function($http) {
    function init(token) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = token || 'Basic xyztoken==';
    }
    return {
        init : init
    };
});
```

On our app.run we initialize the header:

```
app.run(function(api, …) {
    …
    api.init();
    …
});
```

And on our AuthService we set the authorization header with a new token:

```
app.factory('AuthService', function(api, …) {
    …
    // some login action with a response from the REST-API and 
    // set the new authorization header
    api.init('Bearer ' + response.data.accessToken);
    // some more stuff
    …
});
```

And in our controller you don't need to use custom header furthermore.

It only works if you use [credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials). So you must set the withCredential flag on the config phase of your app:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider, …) {
    …
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    …
});
```

Ciao
Ralf

Comment: Hi Ralf thanks for quick reply I tried this it works. However I am getting the same error of 403 forbidden. What should I do.

Comment: Hi @James, sorry for the delay. You must use credentials for your request. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hey Dev thanks, Its okay no problem. But I am still missing something. No problem I will get rid of it soon.